# Issues running Rasa Chatbot on Docker container

Tags: python, docker, containers, chatbot, rasa

i have issues initializing new rasa chatbot.I run ubuntu 22 and this is my docker compose and the output from the docker compose up command.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cZwL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5U86.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIWBO.png

This is everything,i have dir Rasa that i mounted,after the docker compose up i get only .config folder in the mounted folder.That’s it.Please help.I tried a lot of things,but everytime i get this error and i cannot proceed.

Tried different images from dockerhub,different docker compose files,different distribution-CentOS 11,different permissions on the volume

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code. If you need any help, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide the code you are running, the commands you execute and the output errors you get, so it is possible to get help.

Comment: I posted images,there is everything.